# How to change current map in Killing Floor 2?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I join empty server and I want to change its current map. Is there a way to vote for new map? Or is loosing, to force round end, the only option to change current map?

Comment: Tripwire apparently removed the ability to vote for new maps during a round because people were using it to troll others in the first Killing Floor... i.e. waiting until the second to last round to vote for a map change.